# Deletar Registros Duplicados por Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldeveloper

Bom dia,

Alguém sabe se existe a possibilidade de deletar registros duplicados da seguinte forma:

Tenho uma query que traz o resultado

Todos os campos se repetem menos o campo NDO, e NDOGroup, são estes campos que estão duplicando os registros.

Sou obrigada a colocar estes dois campos no meu group by quando dou o select.

Exemplo:

```
 SELECT

   AD.[vch_od],
   MK.NDMarket,  
   MK.TypeMercado,
   MK.NDOrigin as Praça,
   TR.Analyst,
  -- DTB.Season,
 --  DTB.EvDef,
   AD.[dtt_data_captura],
   AD.semana,
   AD.DataMes,
   AD.NDO,
   AD.NDOGroup,
--   PR.valorpremium,  
   AD.[Flt Type],
   IND.[Flt Type],
   AD.[Flt_base] as AD,
   G3.[flt_base] as G3,
   JJ.[flt_base] as JJ,
   OC.[flt_base] as OC,
   P3.[flt_base] as P3
  -- IND.[flt_base] as IND

from #TARIFASAD AD

GROUP BY    
AD.[vch_od],
   MK.NDMarket,  
   MK.TypeMercado,
   MK.NDOrigin,
   TR.Analyst,
 --  DTB.Season,
 --  DTB.EvDef,
  -- AD.NDOGroup,
   AD.[dtt_data_captura],
   AD.semana,
   AD.DataMes,
   AD.NDO,
   AD.NDOGroup,
   --   PR.valorpremium,  
   AD.[Flt Type],
   IND.[Flt Type],
   AD.[Flt_base],
   G3.[flt_base],
   JJ.[flt_base],
   OC.[flt_base],
   P3.[flt_base] 
  -- IND.[flt_base] as IND
```

Hoje meu resultado é este:

```
AJUREC  RECAJU  Monopoly    REC Diego                           12/1/2016   11/27/2016  DRT CNX 415.843396
AJUREC  RECAJU  Monopoly    REC Diego                           12/2/2016   11/27/2016  DRT CNX 303.539575
BPSSSA  SSABPS  Super-Competitive   SSA Diego                           12/1/2016   11/27/2016  DRT CNX 290.775
BPSSSA  SSABPS  Super-Competitive   SSA Diego                           12/2/2016   11/27/2016  DRT CNX 217.514213
```

Não tem registro duplicado. Me traz a média tarifada por data de captura (agrupados)

Preciso inserir as duas colunas NDO, e NDOGroup

que são:

```
NDOGroup
(15-21)
(15-21)
(22-29)
(22-29)
(15-21)
(15-21)

NDO
15
17
20
22
27
29

datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data]) AS NDO, 

  case
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '1' then 'NDO 00'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '5' then'(1-4)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '8' then '(5-7)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'15' then '(8-14)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'22' then '(15-21)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'30' then '(22-29)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'50' then '(30-49)'
  else '50+'
  END AS NDOGroup
```

Eu entendo que o campo dtt_data, mostrado exemplo abaixo, irá diferenciar. Por mais que dtt_captura seja dia 12/01/2016, em várias linhas o campo dtt_data irá ser diferente. Assim no datadiff acima as vezes vai me dar a diferença de 1 dia, as vezes 3 e assim por diante.

```
dtt_data_captura    dtt_data
12/1/2016   13/3/2016
12/1/2016   16/3/2016
12/1/2016   21/3/2016
12/1/2016   17/3/2016
```

Mas gostaria de encontrar uma forma de trazer o NDOGroup de um grupo só sem repetir:
    NDOGroup
    (15-21)
    (22-29)

```
case
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '1' then 'NDO 00'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '5' then'(1-4)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])< '8' then '(5-7)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'15' then '(8-14)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'22' then '(15-21)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'30' then '(22-29)'
  when datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])<'50' then '(30-49)'
  else '50+'
```

E com um unico campo de NDOGroup trazer o NDO correspondente:

```
datediff(dd,QL2.[dtt_data_captura],QL2.[dtt_data])
```

Eu pensei em algo mais ou menos, deletar registros do campo NDOGroup e NDO me trazendo a menor ou maior

```
 DELETE a FROM #TARIFASAD AS a, nomes AS b WHERE a.vch_od=b.vch_od AND a.NDOGroup < b.NDOGroup
```

Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça algo assim:

```
delete from #tarifasad where ndo in (
select ndo from  (
SELECT

   AD.[vch_od],
   MK.NDMarket,  
   MK.TypeMercado,
   MK.NDOrigin as Praça,
   TR.Analyst,
  -- DTB.Season,
 --  DTB.EvDef,
   AD.[dtt_data_captura],
   AD.semana,
   AD.DataMes,
   AD.NDO,
   AD.NDOGroup,
--   PR.valorpremium,  
   AD.[Flt Type],
   IND.[Flt Type],
   AD.[Flt_base] as AD,
   G3.[flt_base] as G3,
   JJ.[flt_base] as JJ,
   OC.[flt_base] as OC,
   P3.[flt_base] as P3
  -- IND.[flt_base] as IND

from #TARIFASAD AD

GROUP BY    
AD.[vch_od],
   MK.NDMarket,  
   MK.TypeMercado,
   MK.NDOrigin,
   TR.Analyst,
 --  DTB.Season,
 --  DTB.EvDef,
  -- AD.NDOGroup,
   AD.[dtt_data_captura],
   AD.semana,
   AD.DataMes,
   AD.NDO,
   AD.NDOGroup,
   --   PR.valorpremium,  
   AD.[Flt Type],
   IND.[Flt Type],
   AD.[Flt_base],
   G3.[flt_base],
   JJ.[flt_base],
   OC.[flt_base],
   P3.[flt_base] 
  -- IND.[flt_base] as IND 
  ) A  ) AND ....
```

mas faça um select antes para ver se está retornando apenas os registros
que você realmente quer excluir, talvez você tenha que refinar melhor essa
query adicionando outros fitros.

Roteiro de teste para você verificar o funcionamento:

```
create table teste( 
  ndo number(5),
  descricao varchar2(10))

insert into teste values( 1, 'AB' )  
insert into teste values( 1, 'AC' )  
insert into teste values( 1, 'CC' )  
insert into teste values( 2, 'DC' )  

select * from teste  

delete from teste where ndo in (   
select ndo from  (   
SELECT ndo, DESCRICAO FROM TESTE 
GROUP BY ndo, descricao ) a  ) and descricao like 'A%'

select * from teste
```

Verifique no roteiro o funcionamento e depois aplique o mesmo conceito á 
sua tabela.

Comment: Não deletou nenhum registro. Estou verificando outros filtros

Comment: Estranho. Se você faz apenas o primeiro select retorna registros. Certo? Fazendo o segundo deve retornar também, então o delete tem de excluir com certeza.

Comment: Sim, e deu erro no final  )) AND ....

Comment: Fiz uma pequena atualização na resposta.

Comment: Oi, não consegui. Continua com erro e duplicando

Comment: Vamos por parte. O delete funcionou e deletou vários itens. Porém se você refizer seu select original esses itens duplos que já estavam lá, lá  continuam. Não foram excluidos? É isso?

Comment: Eu coloquei essa sua resposta na minha query e não roda, mesmo eu tentando adaptar. Dá um erro nos parenteses que não consigo identificar. Se eu adapto tirado eles não exclui os registros

Comment: Adicionei um roteiro para você testar.